# Select 'like' objects in photoshop and replace them (between multiple layers)?

Tags: user-interface, twitter, photoshop, layer, mockups

I've downloaded a Twitter GUI .psd document. Within this document, the creator has made several tweets, each having his profile pic. You have to drill down through the layers significantly to delete them and you have to do it individually with every tweet. (this process needs to be repeated for screen name etc if you want to personalize it for a client)

Is there a way for photoshop to search through the layers and isolate 'like'/'same' images and replace them with images of the same dimension with fewer steps?

Thanks!

p.s. I'm using Adobe Photoshop CS 5 in 32 bit mode on a macbook (I got in 2010).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

> To select all layers of a similar type (for example all type layers),
>   select one of the layers, and choose Select > Similar Layers.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-78d2a.html

This is as far as Photoshop can go on Layer selection. Only vector oriented programs can dive in colour and detail related selections.